# simulate parameter as string with quotation marks (vba)

Tags: string, excel, vba

My function is expecting a parameter like this:

```
myFunc(var as string) as boolean
   'code
end function
```

Typically it gets passed things like: `"978123qq123"`
However, if it gets passed that same variable without the "" meaning: `978123qq123`, it fails. How can I simulate the same behavior of being passed in with quotation marks?

I tried some of the following: `var = " " & var` , `var = " " & var & " "` , `var = cstr(var)` but I can't seem to get my parameter to simulate the effect of being passed into the function with the quotation marks in place.

Comment: Put **[Option 
Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** statement at the top of each newly created code sheet.

Comment: @Jeeped, care to elaborate? I wonder if this is for a UDF.

Comment: FYI, it works for me doing a simple `Debug.Print`. I think you need to expand your question to include a reproducible example and the error you're receiving. Also, is this a UDF?

Comment: If you pass an undeclared var into the function (which is expecting a string) then you will receive **Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch**. You can avoid these sort of errors before attempting runtime with **Option Explicit** since that would REQUIRE you to declare you vars before running it. In that case, you would receive **Compile error: variable not defined** and you can deal with it before attempting runtime.

Comment: @DougGlancy - If this was used on a worksheet then it should return a `#NAME!` error since the string could not be found as a defined name.

Comment: @Jeeped, I was just passing a number (didn't notice the 2 q's in the middle, and that was working. Now I see what you mean about Option Explicit - and the UDF.

Comment: to start a Function, you need the first line of it to start like this `Function` ....

Answer (score 0):

to pass with quotation mark call the function like this :

```
VariableA = MyFunc( chr(34) & var & chr(34) )
```

or

```
VariableA = MyFunc( """ & var & """ )
```